# If i have a column, activity_year_and_month, that has data like 201901-201907

Tags: sql, netezza

If I have a column, `activity_year_and_month`, that has data like 201901-201907, how can I filter my data in the `where clause` to only care about data now - 3 months prior? Looking for the SQL code to do that. Right now I get ERROR **[HY000] ERROR:  Bad timestamp external representation '201812'**

I tried

```
(ACTIVITY_YEAR_AND_MONTH) >= (DATE_TRUNC('MONTH', NOW()) - INTERVAL '3 MONTH')
```

Comment: I think you need more sample data to explain what you want.  What do the two dates in the column represent?

Comment: What is the data type of activity_year_and_month?  Is "201901-201907" contained in one row, or is the hyphen meant to indicate a range of dates across many rows?  Should the sql return only a single month of data, or all months of data from 3 mo prior thru now?